# How to write text on image like comments android?

Tags: android, canvas

I am work on project that take pics from and gallery, I want add text like comments on image

Image set in canvas they have perform some drawing.

Then I want to add text on that image.

Like blue app

[PicSay App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shinycore.picsayfree&hl=en)

Comment: I can only see some ImageViews and some TextViews overlaid on a background... What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can overlay some text/view over another view with:

- FrameLayout, easy
- ImageView, using both background and image source, easy but limited to images
- Custom view overriding onDraw() and superimposing text/views over it, harder

In the third approach you are completely in charge of the drawing. For instance, to draw a bitmap over the content of your custom view, you can override onDraw() like this:

```
protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);
}
```

Comment: FrameLayout +1, because you can move the text later if you want (i used this method for a slide text in a slideshow app)

Answer (score 1):

there are quite a few steps for this which involve text, bitmap, canvas, rect. For example :

```
  int textSize = textSizeBar.getProgress();
  String textToDraw = textIn.getText().toString();

  Bitmap newBitmap = bitmapOriginal.copy(bitmapOriginal.getConfig(), true);

  Canvas newCanvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
  Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
  paint.setColor(Color.RED);
  paint.setTextSize(textSize);

  Rect bounds = new Rect();
  paint.getTextBounds(textToDraw, 0, textToDraw.length(), bounds);
  int x = 0;
  int y = newBitmap.getHeight();

  newCanvas.drawText(textToDraw, x, y, paint);

  image1.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
  image2.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
```

This example is taken from this very good web site : http://android-er.blogspot.com

The full code can be found here : http://android-er.blogspot.com/2015/03/draw-text-on-bitmap.html

Thank you.